# Prevent checkElementIndex() Guava function from concatenating additional response to existing error message

Tags: exception, junit, guava

```
Preconditions.checkElementIndex(startIndex, personMemberGroupMap.keySet().size(), "Error: Offset exceeds the total number of records that can be displayed");
```

The above code checks if the given index is present in the personMemberGroup map. If it isn't then I throw a error message. This error message is then added to the IndexOutOfBounds exception that is thrown.

I have a test case in jUnit to test the above statement. In this test case I check the error message that is passed with the exception.

```
assertEquals("Error: Offset exceeds the total number of records that can be displayed", e.getMessage());
```

But the assertion turns out to be false and the actual message in the exception states

```
"Error: Offset exceeds the total number of records that can be displayed (3) must be less than size (3)"
```

The string `displayed (3) must be less than size (3)` was appended by the `badElementIndex()` method within the Preconditions class.

How do I evaluate my error message. Is there a way of preventing it from appending the extra message or am I providing the error message in the wrong format?

Answer (score 3):

`Preconditions.checkElementIndex()` always formats the message of the exception.

You can see for yourself the call to `badElementIndex()` on [line 305](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java?name=release14#305).